# CSS class attributes changing based on different parent classes

Tags: css, stylus

I'm having some problems trying to override a class. All this happens inside Jekyll and I'm using Stylus for the CSS.

I'm using an inline SVG saved in an html file, which I include at the beginning of the page body.
There are 6 path elements, and each has one of 3 different classes: fill-color1, fill-color2, fill-color3.

```
<symbol id="my-icon" viewBox="0 0 5461 1024">
  <title>my-icon</title>
  <path class="fill-color1" d="M33.706 ..."></path>
  ...
</symbol>
```

I use this SVG in 2 different parts of my website with different backgrounds, so I decided it would be nice to assign different colors to the fill elements.

In the HTML I call the SVG in this way:

```
<svg class="class1 class2 class3">
<use xlink:href="#my-icon"></use></svg>
```

Where class1 and class2 are classes I use also for other image (these do not contain the fill element), and class3 is the one I would use (of course with two different names) to change the behavior of the fill element, so that in one case I would have:

```
<svg class="class1 class2 class3a">
<use xlink:href="#my-icon"></use></svg>
```

and in the second case:

```
<svg class="class1 class2 class3b">
<use xlink:href="#my-icon"></use></svg>
```

The problem is that I don't understand how it should be in the CSS. I tried in several ways and I'm only able to assign a color for both instances, and not for a single one. I suppose I'm having some problem with changing behavior od different descents element, but I'm not even sure. How should the CSS be in order to work?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want this:

```
.class3a
    .fill-color1
        fill red
.class3b
    .fill-color1
        fill blue
```

Comment: This is what I thought as well, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work? Both are same color? Both change color? Or none change the color?

Comment: Like this it doesn't change the color. I tried many different things and it doesn't seem to work. I put here some files:
https://gist.github.com/djangoshark/5408be741f541fcd3295
https://gist.github.com/djangoshark/351967e54b60107ebedf
https://gist.github.com/djangoshark/dc4528b5b4bd94bc4cdf